# Преобразование экспоненциальной формы в число

Tags: javascript

У меня считается среднее арифметическое. sum (number) - сумма по массиву (другой метод  82.096 число, как правило не очень большое, а quant(number) - 12096000000.

Мне нужно, чтобы возвращалось значение в форме обычного числа, к примеру, 0.00000000067, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
    var average = sum/quant; /*среднее тип number значение 6.787202380952381e-9*/
    return average; //должно возвращать тип number
```

Comment: так тип `number` и возвращается.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18719775/6275986